# Import and Export last profile picture to AD

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, profile-sync, picture

I actually want to have a perfect sync of my Sharepoint site with my AD for profile picture. So, I need to have a bi-directionnal import of profile picture and a mean to have the most recent picture on AD and SP Database. But when I go in "User Properties" in AD SYNC (service application) and in "Image", I can only choose Export or Import but not both of them... If you have a piece of advice, It will very please me.

Sorry for my poor English and thank you by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have a one way sync of user profile properties between AD en SharePoint. You cannot import *and* export attributes at the same time unfortunately.

More info at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188041.aspx and http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx (search for the keyword "direction" in both articles)

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid answer ! Do you know if it is possible to sync in both directions not at the same time but alternately ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Perhaps you could do this in the FIM client, but that's absolutely not supported. In fact, when you do, SharePoint will wipe all your manual changes when changing the sync connection in SharePoint.

Comment: Ok thank you again ! Do you think it could work if I add a second connection to the same domain ? Because I'm affraid it will copy all profiles

Comment: Unfortunately I try to add a second sync connection to the same domain but it didn't work. The direction of the first connection I configure is the one used for all others connections even if it's not the same domain....